# Remove grayscale from picture when hovering over a link

Tags: html, css

EDIT: I solved this problem by making the entire image a link, and the text (former link) that was on the picture i put - pointerevents: none. That way I sort of accomplished what I wanted.

[I put image, im hovering over the link that is colored, I want the corresponding picture (top left) to remove grayscale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IJm1.png)I have pictures on a page when you hover over them they turn from grayscale to normal colored picture. By default they are seen as grayscale.

Then I have links on that page as well. What I was is, when I hover mouse over link 1 id like the picture 1 to change from grayscale to normal. Same with link 2 and picture 2.

As if mouse was in 2 places at the same time, hovering on link and picture. How can I link them?

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="images/martin.jpg" alt="kisat">
        <div class="linkcontainer"><a class="teksti" href="urheilija.html">URHEILIJA</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add relevant code here to get help.

Comment: @Ettur Do you mean to ask, what to do if the link is on the picture?

Comment: i have four pictures as a layout of the page. in the middle where they connect i have 4 link menu. I want each link to highlight (remove grayscale) from one of the pictures. First link hover would remove top left picture grayscale, 2nd link hover to remove top right picture grayscale.

Right now I have working that when you hover mouse just over picture it removes grayscale but I want this to happen when going over link as well.

Picture and links are not on top of one another.

Im trying to figure out how to post code here, this is my first topic I just joined and am very beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the link is directly inside the picture:

```
#link:hover > #picture { gray-scale: 0; }
```

If link is next to (after picture closing tag) the picture:

```
#link:hover + #picture { gray-scale: 0; }
```

If the link is somewhere inside the picture:

```
#link:hover #picture { gray-scale: 0; }
```

If the link is a sibling of the picture:

```
#link:hover ~ #picture { gray-scale: 0; }
```

Solution example:

```
<div class="image">
  <a href='...'>LINKTEXT</a>
  <img id="img" src="...">
</div>

<style>
  .image { position: relative; }
  .image a {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  a:hover + #img { filter: grayscale(0); }
  #img { filter: grayscale(1); }
</style>
```

Comment: Nico, i made it so that the link is on picture now. Its in one corner. So I should use #link:hover > #picture { gray-scale: 0; }

Where do I put that code into ? Im sorry if its too simple question, Im just starting out with few weeks into html / css.

Comment: <div class="image">
        <img src="images/martin.jpg" alt="kisat">
            <div class="linkcontainer"><a class="teksti" href="urheilija.html">URHEILIJA</a></div>
    </div>

this is where the picture and link are

Comment: The issue is that your siblings are the following elements. In your code your picture is before your link. I recommend to change that and to work with absolut position to bring your link to the corner. For more details how to fake following sibling (and to keep your html like it is): https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-the-impossible-possible-in-css-with-a-little-creativity-bd96bb42b29d

Comment: I changed the order, I call link before image. And I use relative / absolute positioning to bring link to picture corner. Is it possible now to remove grayscale when i hover link? Is it on the lines of code you posted above? And if so, where do i put it :)? 

 <div class="image">
       <div class="linkcontainer" style="border-top-left-radius: 0.5vw"><a class="teksti" href="urheilija.html">URHEILIJA</a></div>
            <img src="images/martin.jpg" alt="kisat">
            
       </div>

Comment: I "sort of" of solved this by making the entire image a link, and the text (former link) that was on the picture i put - pointerevents: none. That way I sort of accomplished what I wanted.